# Suddenly get SKErrorDomain Code=0 in In-App Purchase response

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We are testing In-App Purchases using sandbox account in our application and today they suddenly stop working.

We checked in debug mode and found that sometimes **SKProductsRequest** returns our products in "**invalidProductIdentifiers**" property and after a few requests it returns them as valid in "**products**" property.

When it returns products as valid and we try to make purchase, we are getting response with **SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed** in **transactionState** property.

We checked **transaction.error** property and it says:

**Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x339120 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}.**

We checked all settings in itunesconnect and on developer portal.
In-App Purchases are setup correctly, App Id is active and In-App Purchases are enabled for it both for Development and Distribution modes.

We tried to make purchase on many devices with different sandbox accounts.
We even tried to create new sandbox account, but it didn't help, we still getting same errors from StoreKit.

Please note, that yesterday all worked correctly, we were able to make test purchases on same sandbox account for same In-App Purchase id.

Can anybody help us with this issue?

Maybe somebody already faced such problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue as your. I checked everything at itunesconnect and apple's developer portal. But everything was correct there. After a long research found that due to Appstore id password in my device was making this error. I logout that from setting in device. Then purchase again app asked me for credentials. I enter sandbox id-password and it worked.

Hope this work for you as well. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the issue!

Comment: ohk, so were able to solve issue? What was causing problem?

Comment: I did end up able to fix the issue. We had added a new developer, so I needed to go, in Xcode, to Preferences -> Accounts -> AppleID -> then I clicked "Download All Profiles" and that cleared it all up

Comment: Great, Congrats!!